# NHibernate could not synchronize database state with session

Tags: c#, nhibernate, concurrency, optimistic-locking

I was checking log files of NHibernate, and found out random errors, as below:

```
NHibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [MaltaIndependent.Modules._AutoGen.MemberImpl#353796206]
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session) in c:\Repository\Work\CodeBase\C#\+OpenSource\nHibernate\nhibernate-core-master-v3.3.1\src\NHibernate\Persister\Entity\AbstractEntityPersister.cs:line 2821
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.UpdateOrInsert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session) in c:\Repository\Work\CodeBase\C#\+OpenSource\nHibernate\nhibernate-core-master-v3.3.1\src\NHibernate\Persister\Entity\AbstractEntityPersister.cs:line 2702
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Int32[] dirtyFields, Boolean hasDirtyCollection, Object[] oldFields, Object oldVersion, Object obj, Object rowId, ISessionImplementor session) in c:\Repository\Work\CodeBase\C#\+OpenSource\nHibernate\nhibernate-core-master-v3.3.1\src\NHibernate\Persister\Entity\AbstractEntityPersister.cs:line 3007
   at NHibernate.Action.EntityUpdateAction.Execute() in c:\Repository\Work\CodeBase\C#\+OpenSource\nHibernate\nhibernate-core-master-v3.3.1\src\NHibernate\Action\EntityUpdateAction.cs:line 79
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable) in c:\Repository\Work\CodeBase\C#\+OpenSource\nHibernate\nhibernate-core-master-v3.3.1\src\NHibernate\Engine\ActionQueue.cs:line 136
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list) in c:\Repository\Work\CodeBase\C#\+OpenSource\nHibernate\nhibernate-core-master-v3.3.1\src\NHibernate\Engine\ActionQueue.cs:line 125
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions() in c:\Repository\Work\CodeBase\C#\+OpenSource\nHibernate\nhibernate-core-master-v3.3.1\src\NHibernate\Engine\ActionQueue.cs:line 171
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session) in c:\Repository\Work\CodeBase\C#\+OpenSource\nHibernate\nhibernate-core-master-v3.3.1\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\AbstractFlushingEventListener.cs:line 241
```

Regarding this issue, I know this happens due to optimistic concurrency and is 'expected' to happen.  My main issue is the stack trace - Nowhere does it state 'where' it happened, and it starts the line `NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecution`.  I tried downloading the NHibernate source code and taking a look, but couldn't make much sense as to why no complete stack trace is shown.  I have other stack traces for similar errors which take me down to the `Transaction.Commit()` line.  Any ideas how I can find which piece of code is actually throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem,  and it turned out I had LazyLoad setup on a mapped field (not a reference or hasmany).

NH should give you which object has caused the error

Hope you get this solved soon